Understanding ICMPv6 checksum verification
As part of a ping command reimplementation managing the IPV4 and IPV6 protocols in the most trivial way possible, I would have liked to understand the verification of checksums on an ICMPv6 packet since the calculation on the outgoing packet is delegated to the TCP / IP stack, unlike IPV4 which is calculated manually which allows us to trace the validity of the packet on the return.
For ICMPv4 I use this reference -> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1071#section-4.1

That is a statement. Is there a question?

The question is here basically "I would have liked to understand the verification of checksums on an ICMPv6", how is it managed in the received packet ? @500-InternalServerError

That is a research type question - too broad for SO. I'm sure it's documented in one or more RFCs - have you tried searching for those?

The only part about verifications / authentication i found in related RFC's - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2463#section-5.1, nothing about the calculation by the TCP/IP stack, one solution would be to calculate it yourself with a pseudo ipv6 header, but I prefer to delegate this as it is planned by default (automatic calculation) @500-InternalServerError

Section 2.3 "Message Checksum Calculation"

The description "1's complement sum" is the same as the general Internet checksum, which is explained in detail in RFC 1071.

@Barmar They are slightly different, v6 performs its calculation on the whole packet, v4 only on the whole header.

Otherwise it still does not explain how the checksum verification is carried out on the return on requests with ICMPv6 when it was calculated automatically on send. When I ask how, it is not the algorithm I am looking for but who is responsible at the reception for the verification in this case @Barmar

This is sounding much less like a programming question, if you're asking how this is implemented in a particular TCP/IP stack.

What matters to me is mainly to know if I have responsibility for checking the checksum at the programming level, you got the point ? @Barmar

No, the stack does this automatically.

good, thanks @Barmar
